# Which C++ libraries should I use for a large parallel computing number-crunching project exploiting third-party applications

Tags: c++, python, user-interface, parallel-processing, linear-algebra

**Introduction**

I want to request a lot of advice on a new programming project I am going to start on my own. I am going to be very precise in what I would like to accomplish and in what my basic requirements are. Therefore this is going to be a long question. Please bear with me.

I am going to split the question into five sections:

1. Real-world problem
2. Simulation problem
3. Requirements and preferences
4. Additional information
5. List of advice requests

**1. Real-world problem**

Skyscrapers and large bridges suffer from dynamic wind loading. This means, when designed incorrectly they can collapse due to wind-induced vibrations (this actually happened in 1940: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mclp9QmCGs). To design such structures correctly, efficient number-crunching software is required for analysis and simulation.

**2. Simulation problem**

There exists a multitude of software capable of either simulating fluid flows or structural mechanics. Many have already been developed for over 30 years and are proven and mature technologies. Writing a multi-physical program capable of simulating both fluid flows and structural mechanics simultaneously from scratch, is therefore unwise. First of all, you would need years of development before reaching maturity and it is very hard to enter a world which has depended on specific software for over 30 years. But more important...why recreate when you can reuse? Instead of pursuing a monolithic approach, I prefer a partitioned approach where I can reuse existing simulation software.

In the partitioned approach I will use software X to simulate flows and I will use software Y to simulate structures. Then I will write my own coupling algorithm which establishes communication between X and Y and uses them to simulate the multi-physical problem (e.g. wind-induced vibrations of skyscrapers or bridges). The reason I use X and Y and not actual software names is because X and Y are supposed to be black-boxes. In no way is my coupling algorithm to be dependent on the implementation of X and Y. The algorithm will only depend on the output of X and Y. This way an end-user can select which ever X or Y is available to them or which ever X or Y is capable of doing what the end-user wants to achieve.

Because I want to use a black-box partitioned approach, software X knows nothing of Y and vice-versa. But how do I simulate the deformation of a bridge without knowing anything of the surrounding air flow and how to I know in which way the surrounding air flow is perturbed by the structure without knowing anything about its deformation? The answer is simple: start with a guess and use an iterative approach to converge to the correct solution. This approach is however very computationally expensive. To reduce the computational cost the coupling algorithm can be written in a clever way using very efficient technologies, not to be discussed here. All I would like to say is that some heavy linear algebra number-crunching is required.

**3. Requirements and preferences**

What I need to do is:

- establish communication between third-party open-source or proprietary software
- perform some heavy number-crunching (linear algebra)
- visualise results (2D / 3D plotting and animating)
- deliver an interactive analysis and development environment
- create an intuitive graphical user interface

What I want my software to be:

- open-source
- cross-platform
- extendable through scripts and/or shared libraries

What I am going to use:

- C++ for heavy number-crunching
- CPython for programming logic
- NumPy / SciPy for some number-crunching in CPython
- Matplotlib for results visualisation in CPython

**4. Additional information**

Facts:

- one-man project at start, grow to company if successful
- primary OS is a KDE-based Linux distribution

Business model:

- Free software and basic documentation.
- Paid services and elaborate documentation.

**5. List of advice requests**

I want to do all number-crunching in C++ by writing many functions which individually perform just a tiny task. The program logic is to be contained in a CPython package which executes the entire simulation while relying on the C++ functions to perform the number-crunching. The C++ / CPython algorithm is to be extended with scripts written in CPython (using NumPy, SciPy, SymPy and Matplotlib) to generate and visualise results from raw numerical data. I want to be able to do parallel computing and I need to communicate with several third party open-source AND proprietary software.

To accomplish all that I am going to need a whole bunch of existing libraries/packages/technologies etc. And to all relevant issues I know what I can use, however I do not know what I should use. The best solution is as always to try everything out and see what works best. However if any experienced user can weed out some of the more unlikely candidates I would gladly receive his or hers advice, suggestion, pro / con list on:

1. Glueing C++ and CPython (e.g. CTypes, SIP, SWIG etc.)
2. C++ linear algebra number-crunching library (e.g. Armadillo, Eigen, PETSc etc.)
3. Graphical interface development library (e.g. Qt, GTK, wxWidgets etc.)
4. Software communication and parallel computing (e.g. MPICH, OpenMPI, OpenMP etc.)
5. CPython 2.7.x or CPython 3.x

NOTE: I have summed some options above, but these are only exemplary and not a limitation to. I am open to everything as long as it is written in C, C++, Fortran or Python. Also I do not expect an answer in all five categories enlisted above from one individual. Let the collective knowledge of the community take care of that.

I thank all contributors and wish you all the best of luck in your own endeavors.

Comment: Don't know of any but giving you an up vote cause its cool to learn about structural engineering

Comment: Thank you Greg for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical interface development library (e.g. Qt, GTK, wxWidgets etc.)**
If your "primary OS is a KDE-based Linux distribution", then QT wins this one hands down.
Logic behind this:-

- KDE is writen in QT. A QT app running in KDE is an eagle in the air! It's in its element. With KDE Being target number 1, your QT GUI will most likely work out of the box without users having to download additional gui libs. Your GUI will also look super native.
- QT is the most portable of the three. (you mentioned "primary OS", hinting that other platforms might follow). Therefore with qt you can port to Windows, OSX, GNOME, Embeded Linux, Android, Symbian, HAIKU, Solaris ..etc
- QT has arguably the best RAD tools of the top three cross platform GUI libs (IMHO). Think QTCreator vs wxSmith vs Anjuta/Glade.
- wxWidgets on linux is basically a wapper for GTK+ (v1 to v3) + additional helpers. Tho I preffer it over GTK. It also wraps around X11 and motif but trust me chief, you will not like those ports.
- wxWidgets portability is not as seamless as one would think. Each port is a totaly different implementation, each wrapping totally different backends! I once ported a small app that uses wxDataViewCtrl with a custom tree model. SIGSEGVs became the order of the day. So I eventually decided to go with the generic wxDataViewCtrl (that looks funny in GTK+3). I still like wxWidgets tho.

***NB: Consider also using the latest web technologies for the C&V part of the MVC (model view controller).***
HTML5+CSS3+JS can be run by a web-view widget on a desktop app. All the above 3 GUI Libs sport this control (for wx, it's wx2.9.3 and above). 
Web technologies:-

- Have (arguably) the fastest time-to-market of any GUI lib.
- Have (arguably) the most available and affordable developers of any GUI technology today.
- Produce the most stunning UIs of any GUI lib.
- Produce the least "RIGID" UIs of any GUI lib....you can rotate a gui element e.g. a html table around any axis with fancy animation just by mouse over, without any programming overhead!..no js..no c++..nada!

**CPython 2.7.x or CPython 3.x**
 - CPython might not be well suited to your project's requirements (I think) chiefly because of the mutex monster that is the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) bottleneck.
Maybe PyPy would be a better python implementation for your project?

***By the way, have you also considered:- Javascript on V8 vs. Python (PyPy,CPython et. all)?***
[Javascript run by V8 can interact with Native Code (c++)](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#templates) sort of like Ctypes with python
I also came across this [interesting blog](http://blog.bossylobster.com/2011/08/lesson-v8-can-teach-python-and-other.html) (JS on V8 vs Py).

Comment: Haha Qt it is. I haven't considered web technologies. I mainly want to keep the GUI tight and simple. Just a few windows to select options graphically instead of manually editing a configuration file or using a ton of command-line arguments. For 2D/3D visualisation of data sets I am considering embedding [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) entirely. I prefer CPython for it's extensive list of scientific libraries. I do not know if JS is any good in linear algebra. For speed NumPy is a must and PyPy does not support it. Another option is to JIT CPython through [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Comment: But thanks Moje, I will for sure have a look on JS with V8. I will also look into the web technologies if I have some time.

Comment: I get it now...vote QT then. 
Definitely currently JS is not good for linear algebra, but again, are you going leave that heavy math to Python alone?
Wont your scripts be calling math FXns from "C/C++ number crunching libs"?

Comment: The idea is to use C/C++ libraries to perform the entire simulation. However I want to post-process the raw numerical data with Python scripts. Consider this simple example. I will solve the differential equations governing a flow around a car using C/C++ libraries. But I will use a Python script that uses the raw pressure distribution data to compute the total down force on the car.

Comment: Ok. I went thru your post afresh (at first i had only skimmed thru :) ).I now have a better appreciation of Python's role in your project. Anyway, i got you covered on the GUI part - it's QT without a doubt. As for the python bit, i would say you are in your element. Question is, considering your time to market requirement, would you consider it wise to go with the python libs you're most comfy with.....and then maybe distribute R&D on the same throughout successive versions?

Comment: Hi Moje, thanks for your interest. Unfortunately I do not understand your last question :( ps: I don't have a time to market requirement.

Comment: Oh sorry. What i mean't with time to market is how soon you would like to launch your project for public use...for the benefit off all mankind. I got a sense of this coz you mentioned that you have a business model. If this aspect of the project is urgent, then maybe one important factor for choosing the software stack (CPython,NumPy)  is going with those that the development team is most familiar with as opposed conducting R&D to find the most optimal solution...(I apologize in advance for thinking too much like a manager :) )

Comment: Ah, that is indeed very wise. However I will start with the project on my own. When it gets some momentum I will contact some uni mates who I know that have experience with Python. Also with the popularity of Python these days, I don't think finding qualified developers will be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You mention parallelism but not how you intend to make this project parallel. This is a much more complex issue than simply choosing a couple libraries. There are several major considerations required before moving forward.

You mention the intended platform briefly, but you also have to consider whether the simulation will be run on a single computer/node or multiple. Considering that you are doing an iterative simulation of a building, you are probably going to require far more compute power than any one computer can provide. This means that, unless you want to go with a hybrid multiple-process, multiple-thread approach, you are limited to a multiple-process model of parallelism. OpenCL and MPI are then each options for your implementation. (note: MPICH and OpenMPI are each just implementations of MPI, and your code should be agnostic of these) Message passing with MPI is a good general model of parallelism however it can be quite difficult for those not used to working with parallel code. My personal experience is with MPI and some hybrid programming so I cannot say much else regarding your choice of parallel model.

A problem that follows from the issue of the parallel model is that it directly impacts the simulation software. I am not entirely certain how separate you are planning on keeping your algorithm from the simulations. If you plan to have your code fork separate process to run the simulations, you will have issues with cross-platform support as you may not have the luxury of being able to run arbitrary simulations in this manner. If you instead intend to run the simulations within your software, the parallel model has to be consistent throughout. Although this puts limitations on the black box strategy, it may make the entire thing that much more feasible.

A good deal has already been said about applicable libraries. I don't have any more to say about specific libraries that hasn't already been said. Just keep in mind that many of the same issues have to be addressed with these as when running the simulations.

TLDR: Parallelism should not be looked over. You need to know which parallel model that you will be using before making decisions on libraries.

Comment: Thanks corahm for you input. Of all the topics I discussed in my original post, GUI programming and parallelism are the two topics I have the least experience with (close to none). I need to do some extensive reading in those fields. Could you suggest me any useful books or url's for parallelism?

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about MPI, I have read Parallel Programming with MPI by Peter Pacheco which is somewhat older. He also wrote Introduction to Parallel programming which should also be good. Otherwise, a few Google searches on threading, message passing, OpenCL, etc can go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, gmp.  You can find more details here: http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Wow, that is really quick. Thank you I will have a look.

Comment: I have had a quick look. GMP looks great but is not really what I need. I did not find algorithms for solving linear systems (e.g. BiCG, GMRES etc.) or non-linear systems (e.g. Newton-Raphson). Or performing regular linear algebra tasks (eigenvalues, determinant, inverse).

Comment: Possibly, blas and lapack may be of interest then.  Check those links: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ and http://www.netlib.org/blas/

Comment: Those are indeed good libraries. Optimised versions are available in ATLAS and Armadillo adds a nice API on top of it making the syntax MATLAB-like.

Comment: [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) is a highly optimised  version of BLAS and LAPACK. It uses multi-threading (parallel processing), and can be linked with Armadillo.

Comment: Installing ATLAS is quite a pain. A lot of documentation to read through and a lot of command-line parameters to add for optimal performance. Never heard of OpenBLAS before, however a quick Google search has taught me that it is faster than ATLAS. I will give it a go after I find out how to use it with Armadillo. Thanks mtall!

Comment: I went through the pain of installing ATLAS again. I managed to pull through...but wooh OpenBLAS is so much easier to install. Also considering the fact that is gets better reviews than ATLAS, I sincerely thank you mtall for suggesting it! You have my gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like premature optimization.  You need to write code, a lot of code, put lots of prints everywhere to get statistics, then try at least two different approaches to get a benchmark and then make a reasonable decision.  There is no replacement for doing the work, anything else is just handwaving.

Comment: I quote myself:
"The best solution is as always to try everything out and see what works best. However if any experienced user can weed out some of the more unlikely candidates I would gladly receive his or hers advice"

No it's not premature optimisation. It is called literature research / market research. I agree that benchmarking is a must. However starting right away without consulting others who have more experience is just dumb. This is more efficient.